# display content of ul in a div using jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to display contents of unordered list in a div.
each_ex is the id of a link.
list is the id of a list of which I want to display the items of.
msg_ex is the id of div.
here is my jQuery code.

```
$('#each_ex').click(function(){
var str=$("#list").text();
$("#msg_ex").html(str);
});
```

here is the body of the html code. There is no error in it and I am not suppose to change the html. Also script tag is added but I did not write it here:

```
<div class="men_ex">
<ul id="list">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">products</a></li>
<li><a href="#">services</a></li>
<li><a href="#">about</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<a href="#" id="each_ex">Display</a>
<div id="msg_ex"></div>
```

basically it prints the content of list in a line but I want it to diplay each element in a new line, but I can't seem to do it..
What should I do.

Comment: Please show us your html, without it, it's hard to give you a good answer

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I just did. Can u help me out ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try do it like this:

```
$('#each_ex').click(function() {
  var str = $("#list li").map(function() { return $(this).text() + "<br>" }).get();
  $("#msg_ex").html(str);
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('#each_ex').click(function() {
  var str = $("#list li").map(function() { return $(this).text() + "<br>" }).get();
  $("#msg_ex").html(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="men_ex">
  <ul id="list">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">products</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" id="each_ex">Display</a>
<div id="msg_ex"></div>
```